# Why is Express VPN web server send back a 404 or 403 error code when I sent python request for login in

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests, python-requests-html

Why is Express VPN web server send back a 404 or 403 error code when I sent python request for login in

```
s = requests.Session()

urls = {'getAuthUrl': 'https://www.expressvpn.com/sign-in', 'loginUrl': 'https://www.expressvpn.com/sessions'}

authPage = s.get(urls['getAuthUrl'], headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36', 'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,ar;q=0.8'})

xv_web_frontend_session = authPage.cookies['_xv_web_frontend_session']
xvid = authPage.cookies['xvid']
xvgtm = authPage.cookies['xvgtm']
landing_page = authPage.cookies['landing_page']

head = {
          'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7'.encode('utf-8'),
          'Cookie': f'landing_page={landing_page}; xvid={xvid}; xvsrcwebsite=www.expressvpn.com; xvsrcdirect=1; xvgtm={xvgtm}; locale=; _uetsid=6eb616d01f5811eebb357771af68c63c; _uetvid=0a2cce00072d11eebb2279b32a2beda5; _xv_web_frontend_session={xv_web_frontend_session}',
          'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,ar;q=0.8', 
          'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'.encode('utf-8')
        }

authKeySoup = bs(authPage.text, 'html.parser')

authKey = authKeySoup.find(name='input', attrs={'name': 'xkgztqpe'})['value']

payloadToSend = {
                    'utf8': '\xe2\x9c\x93',
                    'xkgztqpe': authKey,
                    'location_fragment': '',
                    'd2b6c54d': '',
                    'redirect_path': '',
                    'email': 'email',
                    'password': 'password',
                    'commit': 'Sign In'
                }

loginRequest = s.post(urls['loginUrl'], data=json.dumps(payloadToSend), cookies=authPage.cookies, headers=head, allow_redirects=True)
```

and when I Send the request i got response with status code 403 or 404 and sometimes 400 any help please ??

Comment: Why not asking directly to ExpressVPN support?